# General question: Reasons to use sha3 (or any hash) in contracts?

Tags: solidity, sha3, delegatecall, upgrading

I'm going through the Numerai contracts and noticing a common pattern -
 https://github.com/numerai/contract/blob/master/contracts/NumeraireBackend.sol

and https://gist.github.com/Arachnid/4ca9da48d51e23e5cfe0f0e14dd6318f

```
function stakeOnBehalf(address _staker, uint256 _value, bytes32 _tag, uint256 _tournamentID, uint256 _roundID, uint256 _confidence) stopInEmergency onlyPayloadSize(6) returns (bool ok) {
    return delegateContract.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("stakeOnBehalf(address,uint256,bytes32,uint256,uint256,uint256)")), _staker, _value, _tag, _tournamentID, _roundID, _confidence);
}
```

I see the delegatecall with the `bytes4` and get the `sha3` hash of a string before the variables of the function. I understand what `sha3` does in this context, but my question is why?

Is it for security? What is the purpose of the string before the variables as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That string is called the function selector. It is calculated as the first four bytes of the `sha3` hash of the signature of the function. The signature is defined as the canonical expression of the basic prototype, i.e. the function name with the parenthesised list of parameter types. Parameter types are split by a single comma - no spaces are used (as you can also observe in the code snippet you provided).

Function selectors are used to tell Solidity and EVM which functions you actually want to (delegate) call.

See more info [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#function-selector). 
You might also find this [helpful.](https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide/blob/master/source/contracts-and-transactions/accessing-contracts-and-transactions.rst#interacting-with-smart-contracts)

Comment: Thank you. So to clarify, the EVM will not be able to find the delegatecall function unless I add the function selector?

Comment: Exactly! That's the reason why you have to provide it  ;)

Comment: Thanks again. Having an issue after writing a sample contract to test this. Maybe you can spot the issue I'm having - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27860/delegatecontract-address-getting-reset-on-delegatecall-using-geth-console