# delegateContract address getting reset on delegatecall using geth console

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, sha3, delegatecall

I've deployed the following contracts on the rinkeby testnet. They are completely separate with different addresses:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Backend {

  address public delegateContract;
  address[] public previousDelegates;


  event DelegateChanged(address oldAddress, address newAddress);

  function Backend() {
    // constructor
  }

  function changeDelegate(address _newDelegate) returns (bool) {
    if (_newDelegate != delegateContract) {
          previousDelegates.push(delegateContract);
          var oldDelegate = delegateContract;
          delegateContract = _newDelegate;
          DelegateChanged(oldDelegate, _newDelegate);
          return true;
      }
      return false;

  }

  function add(uint256 var1, uint256 var2) {
    delegateContract.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("add(uint256,uint256)")), var1, var2);
  }

}
```

and

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Delegate {

  uint public total;

  function Delegate() {
    // constructor
  }

  function add(uint256 var1, uint256 var2) {
    total = var1 + var2;
  }
}
```

I'm running some commands in the geth console, I successfully am able to set the `delegateContract` with `changeDelegate` function. Here are the commands in the console:

```
backend.changeDelegate(delegate.address, {from:sender})
"0x3a4e83d03b4c7367eb2ed61630c4809470d3ca5bdedbb02741da7701c0e14b29"
> backend.delegateContract.call()
"0x1eb1746e49ffc5fb38c20ce07242db3bae89c9eb"
> backend.add(1,1,{from:sender})
"0x8cbc47f9f8f2382c10a1d93c47eb9de3e2fb8f6c63b62c387096f6250311c58b"
> backend.delegateContract.call()
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002"
```

When I run the `add` function, it seems to corrupt the previously set `delegateContract` address. When I call `backend.total.call()` no changes are happening.

Any idea why this is occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to declare the `total` variable in the storage of the `Backend` contract. That is the reason why you don't see nothing when you perform `backend.total.call()`.

Regarding the `add` function of your `Backend` contract: when the `add`  function of the `Backend` contract is executed, it uses a delegatecall to your `Delegate` contract. This means that the `add` function of the `Delegate` contract will run in the context of your `Backend` contract. In other words you allow the `Delegate` contract's `add` function to change the `Backend` contract's storage. And here comes the problem. Since you do not have a `total` storage variable in your `Backend` contract, your delegate call will update the storage of the `Backend` contract at some random place or will not modify your storage at all, simply because there is no such field as `total` in the `Backend` contract.

[This](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/difference-between-call-callcode-and-delegatecall) comparison of the different call types is pretty good. You might be interested!

Comment: This is fascinating. I added `total`, `address public delegateContract;` and `address[] public previousDelegates;` for it to finally work. It updated the `total` of the `Backend` contract, not the delegate.

If the whole purpose of this set up is to be able to write upgradeable contracts, how am I able to upgrade the delegate if I am constrained by being unable to new variables or methods?

Comment: Well, you are only constrained to the function signature. So the general idea is that Backend remains intact all the time, you just deploy newer versions of the Delegate contract and adjust accordingly the address of the Delegate contracts in the Backend contract. The assumption is that the delegated function signatures do not change over time....if it changes then obviously you can not call those functions without deploying a new Backend contract.